# Running a Go test with a Transaction

Tags: go, foundationdb

I have Go code using FoundationDB and I want to test it.

I have literally copied the Go [test from Apple's Github](https://github.com/apple/foundationdb/blob/master/bindings/go/src/fdb/fdb_test.go#L87). When I uncomment the line that actually runs `Set` within the transaction, the test hangs and then times out. (With the line still commented out it works as expected.)

```
func TestExampleTransactor(t *testing.T) {
    fdb.MustAPIVersion(400)  // Note: test behaves the same with MustAPIVersion(600)
    db := fdb.MustOpenDefault()

    setOne := func(t fdb.Transactor, key fdb.Key, value []byte) error {
        fmt.Printf("setOne called with:  %T\n", t)
        _, e := t.Transact(func(tr fdb.Transaction) (interface{}, error) {
            // We don't actually call tr.Set here to avoid mutating a real database.
            tr.Set(key, value) // **NOTE** this is the line I uncommented
            return nil, nil
        })
        return e
    }

    setMany := func(t fdb.Transactor, value []byte, keys ...fdb.Key) error {
        fmt.Printf("setMany called with: %T\n", t)
        _, e := t.Transact(func(tr fdb.Transaction) (interface{}, error) {
            for _, key := range keys {
                setOne(tr, key, value)
            }
            return nil, nil
        })
        return e
    }

    var e error

    fmt.Println("Calling setOne with a database:")
    e = setOne(db, []byte("foo"), []byte("bar"))
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("\nCalling setMany with a database:")
    e = setMany(db, []byte("bar"), fdb.Key("foo1"), fdb.Key("foo2"), fdb.Key("foo3"))
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
        return
    }
}
```

I am running MacOS 10.13.6. I have FoundationDB installed and I'm able to connect to it using `fdbcli`, as well as read from and write to it.

Here are the `foundation` processes:

```
ps aux | grep foundation
root             12942   1.0  0.3  4488980  46608   ??  S    12:35PM   2:00.06 /usr/local/libexec/fdbserver --cluster_file /usr/local/etc/foundationdb/fdb.cluster --datadir /usr/local/foundationdb/data/4689 --listen_address
root             12517   0.3  0.1  4382548  12204   ??  S    12:32PM   0:29.63 /usr/local/foundationdb/backup_agent/backup_agent --cluster_file /usr/local/etc/foundationdb/fdb.cluster
bancron          25399   0.0  0.0  4258468    200 s005  R+    2:55PM   0:00.00 grep foundation
root             12515   0.0  0.0  4297540    584   ??  Ss   12:32PM   0:00.01 /usr/local/libexec/fdbmonitor --conffile /usr/local/etc/foundationdb/foundationdb.conf --lockfile /var/run/FoundationDB.pid
```

In case it is relevant, this is the contents of the default cluster file found at `/usr/local/etc/foundationdb/fdb.cluster`:

```
JCKqKWc6:ku0VRske@127.0.0.1:4689
```

And this is the contents of `/usr/local/etc/foundationdb/foundationdb.conf`:

```
[general]
restart_delay = 60
cluster_file = /usr/local/etc/foundationdb/fdb.cluster

## Default parameters for individual fdbserver processes
[fdbserver]
command = /usr/local/libexec/fdbserver
public_address = auto:$ID
listen_address = public
datadir = /usr/local/foundationdb/data/$ID
logdir = /usr/local/foundationdb/logs

## An individual fdbserver process with id 4689
## Parameters set here override defaults from the [fdbserver] section
[fdbserver.4689]

[backup_agent]
command = /usr/local/foundationdb/backup_agent/backup_agent
logdir = /usr/local/foundationdb/logs

[backup_agent.1]
```

Comment: Try to test something simple like getting data from db first. After that you will know if issue is in connection or in transaction.

Comment: I am able to put data in the DB and query it back out via calling `fdb.Database.Transact` code: `Transact` for writing and `ReadTransact` for reading. The code is extremely similar.

Comment: It is just being called over HTTP instead of inside a test. Same `fdb.MustOpenDefault()` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working now by running some fdbserver and fdbcli commands first.

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    port := 4692
    testFileContents := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("test:test%d@127.0.0.1:%d", port, port))
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("fdb_test.cluster", testFileContents, 0755)
    db := fdb.MustOpen("fdb_test.cluster", []byte("DB"))
    mErr := m.Run()
    // ... tests run now

    err = fdbServerCmd.Process.Kill()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error killing fdbserver process %s", err)
    }
    os.Exit(mErr)
}

func createDB() *exec.Cmd {
    port := 4692
    testFileContents := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("test:test%d@127.0.0.1:%d", port, port))
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("fdb_test.cluster", testFileContents, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to write fdb_test.cluster file %s", err)
    }
    fdbServerLoc := "/usr/local/libexec/fdbserver"
    fdbServerCmd := exec.Command(fdbServerLoc,
        "-p", fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", port),
        "--datadir", fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/fdb%d", port),
        "-C", "fdb_test.cluster",
    )
    fdbServerCmd.Start()
    configureLoc := "/usr/local/bin/fdbcli"
    configureCmd := exec.Command(configureLoc,
        "-C", "fdb_test.cluster", "--exec", "configure new single memory")
    // This may error if the DB already exists (from previous test runs), so ignore the error.
    configureCmd.Run()
    return fdbServerCmd
}
```